# React container component's method test with jest

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, redux, jestjs

I want to write unit test for React component's method.

The component's code is

```
        export class LoginForm extends Component {

        constructor() {
            super();
            this.tryLoginProp = this.tryLoginProp.bind(this)
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <div className="login-form">
                    <div className="form-input">
                      <CustomButton label="Log in"
                        class="login-button"
                        action={this.tryLoginProp}
                        id="login-button-loginform"
                        renderSpinner={this.props.renderSpinner}
                      />
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        }

        tryLoginProp () {
          if (!this.props.renderSpinner) {
            this.props.tryLoginProp()
          }
        }
    }

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
      return {
        login: state.login,
        renderSpinner: state.layout.renderSpinner
      };
    };


    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
      tryLoginProp: () => {
        dispatch(tryLogin())
      }
    });

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginForm);
```

I want to write unit test for tryLoginProp method, but I am not getting how to mock this.props.tryLoginProp function and pass the test case.

Current unit test is as follows:

```
 describe('<LoginForm />', () => {

  const initialState = {renderSpinner: false};
  let wrapper;

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(<LoginForm {...initialState}/>);
  });

  it('renders without expolding', () => {
    expect(wrapper.length).toEqual(1);
  });

  it('tryLoginProp should dispatch an action', () => {
    expect(wrapper.tryLoginProp()). //test tryLoginProp method.
  })
});
```

Please help me to write proper test case for this method.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `wrapper.instance().tryLoginProp()` to call the method...like this I think without testing it

```
it('tryLoginProp should dispatch an action', () => {
  const mockedTryLoginProp = jest.fn();
  const wrapper = shallow(
    <LoginForm 
      tryLoginProp={mockedTryLoginProp}
      renderSpinner={false}
    />
  );
  wrapper.instance().tryLoginProp();
  expect(mockedTryLoginProp).toHaveBeenCalled();
})
```

On a side note, you may consider naming the internal function differently than the one being passed in to avoid confusion